# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller

the topic error showing me when I am redirect the view page from controller.

Here is the full error

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The view '~/Views/Udhyog/Services.cshtml' was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Udhyog/Services.cshtml**

Here is my controller code

```
public virtual IActionResult Index()
{
    return View("~/Views/Udhyog/Services.cshtml");
}
```

I am surprised that why this type of error is showing, because In views => Udhyog named one folder and in that I want to show the services.cshtml view page.

So, is there my code wrong or is there any another method to redirect the view page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return View("../UdhyogMaster/Services");